# How do I alter the data type for a column?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am attempting to alter a data type from string to int in column titled Year in Google BigQuery

```
ALTER TABLE `addiction_and_poverty.mental_health`
ALTER COLUMN Year int64
```

I am getting error **"Expected keyword DROP or keyword SET but got identifier."**

I am not sure how to fix this error

Comment: Docs for this feature: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#change_a_columns_data_type

Answer (score 0):

According to DOC: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#change_a_columns_data_type

```
ALTER TABLE addiction_and_poverty.mental_health
ALTER COLUMN Year SET DATA TYPE NUMERIC;
```